# Differentiability of product of functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m} $ and let $ f_{1}:E\to\mathbb{R} $ and $ f_{2}:E\to{{\mathbb{R}}} $ be differntiable in $ x_{0} $.

I want to prove that $ f_{1}f_{2} $ is differntiable in $ x_0 $ based on the definition of differntiability we got.

Thats the definition:

Let $ \varOmega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $ f:\varOmega\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $. We say that $ f $ is differntiable in $ x_0 $ if exists a linear transformation  $ L_{x}:\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that  $ f\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)=L_{x}h+o\left(h\right) $.

Also we denote this linear transformation by $df$.

Now based on this definition here's my attempt to show that the product function is differntiable and that $ d\left(f_{1}f_{2}\right)=f_{1}df_{2}+f_{2}df_{1} $

So I want to show that $ f_{1}f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)=\left(f_{1}df_{2}+f_{2}df_{1}\right)h+o\left(h\right) $

Now:

$ f_{1}f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)=f_{1}\left(x_{0}+h\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right) $

$ =f_{1}\left(x_{0}+h\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)+f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right) $

$ =\left(f_{1}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)\right)f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)+\left(f_{2}\left(x_{0}+h\right)-f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)\right)f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right) $

$ =\left(df_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)h+o\left(h\right)\right)\left(f_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)+df_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)h+o\left(h\right)\right)+\left(df_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)h+o\left(h\right)\right)f_{1}\left(x_{0}\right) $

And now Im stuck because I'll have a product which is not $o(h)$, that is:

$ df_{1}\left(x_{0}\right)h\cdot df_{2}\left(x_{0}\right)h $

^ it will show up when I open the parentheses.

Any advice would help. Thanks

Comment: Of course that term is $o(h)$. Why do you say it is not? (By the way, $h$ is a vector, so I would write $o(\|h\|)$, etc.) Also, your notation is sloppy overall: In the first line ("So I want to show that") you need to evaluate $f_i$ and $df_i$ at the point $x_0$. I haven't read the rest for accuracy.

Comment: You should keep $f_2(x_0+h)$ in the last line. Since $f_2$ is differentiable in $x_0$, it is also continuous in $x_0$. This should allow you to complete the argument.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean this term is $ o(h) $ this term is a real number since $df_1 $ and $df_2 $ are linear operators from $ R^m $ to $ R $

Comment: So what? What do you think $o(h)$ means? I already pointed out that the correct thing to be writing is $o(\|h\|)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin $f(x_0+h)=o(h)$ if $ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{||f\left(x_{0}+h\right)||}{||h||}=0 $. It is not the case here, if you claim otherwise, can you prove please?

Comment: Which is saying, in the usual notation, $o(\|h\|)$. So why do you think your real-valued function has an issue? For any linear map $A$ (in finite dimensions) we have $\|Ah\|\le C\|h\|$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay, $ ||Ah||\leq C||h|| $ how does it mean that $ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{||Ah||}{||h||}=0 $ ?

Comment: @TedShifrin All we can say is that $ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{||Ah||}{||h||}\leq C $

Comment: Your term you asked about was a product of two. Now try!

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, Thanks